# Printing Microsoft Access PDF report to custom size

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf

I need to print a Microsoft Access report to a PDF. The dimensions of the PDF output must be 8.375in x 1.375in (Meaning the entire size of the page must be this size when outputted). Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you set the size of the report to those dimensions and print it?

Comment: @Gustav it prints to the size specified in the Print Setup, which is a predefined list of sizes and does not allow me to enter a custom dimension

Comment: You would have to add those custom paper sizes first, and that's not easily done in code. It also is based on which PDF/Printer driver you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you will have to create this *custom paper size* and assign it to the PDF printer.

Then, prior to printing, set the *Printer object* to use that paper size:

[image]

This can be a bit tricky, and I have never used this, so I can't provide details, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft provide a method to set some printer property`s  [Printer.PaperSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.printer.papersize)

And a [PaperSize enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.acprintpapersize)

other option from [access-programmers.co.uk](https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=261038) is

way to custom the printer papar size; Example my custom size is 200mm x 110mm

1) Go to Control Panel>Administrator Tools>Print Managment>Print Server>Form. In action select manage forms and create a new form saiz, In form decription set the form to 200mm and 110mmm. finaly simply rename the form name as " 200X 110"

2) On Access Report, open the report in design view. In tools bar select page setup > paper size > "200X110"

hope that will help you.....